# Updating and generating a WAR file dynamically through a Java application

Tags: java, war

I am working on a dynamic app generating application in which when a user submits a particular form, a a file gets updated in a pre-build war file and the WAR file is provided to the user. For example, a user fills the form giving all application details and we already have a WAR file in which a few files need to be updated and then the WAR is provided to the user... The user can then deploy that WAR file to have his own application... How can I do that??

Comment: It's a common sense question that how can I get that done... Yet for you have edited the question.....

Comment: The WAR is zip file.  Simply update the needed file and create/update the war file.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why are you dynamically updating a web application archive?  Why are you *allowing* something to dynamically update a web application archive?  What are you really trying to accomplish here?  Updating and modifying a WAR is probably **not** what you want.

Comment: Please read the description properly.... I need to get that done dynamically through an application and not manually..... I need to automate that process.. That's why I have mentioned the cause of my application as well that it is an app to develop apps... An app maker...

Comment: @Makoto I am developing an application based on an API I have developed through which a user can just fill a form and get his own dynamic web application ready... Other things are done.. I just need to update a JSON file in the JAR that has the code for the user's application and then provide that JAR to the user.. But all this shall be done dynamically..

Comment: So...it's more of a partially assembled web application, that needs a little bit of coaxing and information from the end user, then?  Okay.  That makes more sense.  Do you have a *specific* question on that?  While at first, I couldn't understand what you were asking; now that I do, I feel it's way too broad.

Comment: Sure.. The question actually is a bit broad.. Let me help you understand it better.. There will be a deployed application which will be an App Maker in my platform.. An end user can sign into it and he will get a form in which all application details will be filled by that user.. Now when that user submits that form, a JSON file in a separate WAR file needs to be updated with the application details which also can be done.. But all I need to do is that that JSON should be updated and the updated WAR file shall be generated which I don't know how to do..

Comment: In short I just want a particular WAR file to be generated through a java application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating the question.  A war file is in fact a simple zip file in a special structure.  To manipulate you can use the Zip package http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html

Maybe you would want to created the zip file as part of a new release and then modify it afterwards.

so you want to create a zip file with the classes and the lib and the xml that you have locally. create the zip file and rename it to my.war The war file will need to adhere to the war file directory format see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_(Sun)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can a user deploy a ZIP file?? He needs a WAR file to deploy it.. Obviously he can generate a war file manually but I wish to completely automate the process.. Is there a way of generating a WAR file through Java??

Comment: a war file is a zip file.  the extension is simply not zip but war.  Or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: Can that package be used to generate a WAR file??

Comment: Please read the comments in the question.. Have explained my scenario properly there...

Comment: so you want to create a zip file with the classes and the lib and the xml that you have locally.  create the zip file and rename it to my.war  The war file will need to adhere to the war file directory format see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_(Sun)

Comment: But as I said earlier, how can I do this dynamically?? I know all this.. What I don't know is that how can I do this using a Java servlet through another app..

Comment: What I need is a way in Java using which dynamically a WAR file is generated without any human intervention....

Comment: Read my answer again.  When I say "you" I don't mean you. I mean your application.  Use the Zip package then I mentioned.  see http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-files-in-zip-format/